# Set NavigationBar title Font

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uifont

I've been searching for a way to change title font in navigationBar and have made below attempt however nothing happens, the font works fine on UILabel and so on.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: 18) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18)
]
```

Comment: where did you put that code exactly?

Comment: in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Comment: You code working for me.

Comment: You should put this code in the `viewDidLoad` method of your main view controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
    UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor whiteColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor : [UIColor blackColor],
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset : [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1, 0)],
    UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:25.0]
}];
```

in swift

```
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [UITextAttributeTextColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), 
    UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: UIColor.blackColor(), 
    UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: NSValue(UIOffset: UIOffsetMake(1, 0)), 
UITextAttributeFont: UIFont(name: "System", size: 25.0)]
```